# Tags outside the loop

Tags: loop, tags

I want to display the tags of the posts in my main page.

I used:

```
global $post;
the_tags();
```

But it's only showing up for my FIRST page.

Comment: I really don't get it. When I use the_category, it's displaying the category for all of my posts but it's not working with the_tags

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
get_the_tags();
```

With the Post `$id`parameter so it works outside the loop

Source: [`get_the_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php the_tags('Tags: ', ', ', '<br />'); ?>
```

This tag will help to view the tag option in all pages. Please check it let me know for any issues.

Answer (score -2):

try this once

```
$tags = get_tags();
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

    $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
    $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```

Comment: Now it's showing me the tags of the first post on each post

Comment: Please explain why this should work and what your code does. Just dumping code is not a good answer and should be avoided. Thanks for your understanding.